# php, MySQL and variables containing å, ä and ö escape problem

Tags: php, variables, mysql

I'm having some problem with my SQL syntax/escaping variables on my LAMP server.

The command I want to use is the following:

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO '$table' (FirstName, LastName, StartDate, TimeStroke, DueDate, Duration, Price, Retailer, Checksum)
VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[startdate]','$_POST[timestroke]','$duedate','$_POST[duration]','$price','$_SESSION[name]','$random')");
```

The problem is that sometimes the $table variable contains characters like å, ä and ö.
Hence I need to put ' ' around $table to make sure it stays the same. However when doing that recieve the error:

`"Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''tablename' (FirstName, LastName, StartDate, TimeStroke, DueDate, Duration, P' at line 1".`

Looks like the escaping by ' ' creates a problem.
I've tried with replacing the query with a mysql_real_escape_string:

```
"$sql=sprintf("INSERT INTO '".mysql_real_escape_string($table)."' (FirstName, [...]"
```

but that doesnt help me either.
Is there a way to keep the data in the variable intact and still be able to run the query? Or do I have to accept that å,ä,ö is banned from php/MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is do to with character-encoding. Check out http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2006/03/15/do-you-know-your-character-encodings/

---

Put `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` at the top of your page

Also try doing `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` before insert/reading from DB. Then you should put the following on your form that's posting to your PHP file:

```
<form action="/your-post-controller.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Notice the **accept-charset="utf-8** -- this is extremely important otherwise your header will report to the PHP file its in latin1

It should work then.

Also take a look at http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets -- was trying to find the link, definitely worth a read for anyone interested in getting character encoding right, see the `Iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn` string for testing your PHP&MySQL table

Comment: Thanks for that! NIce, but now I'm reciving strange charaters on everything fetched from the database.
Now, do I have to convert the database to be able to fetch info from the tables and then reuse it in the forms?

Comment: What character encoding is the table in? Can you give examples of "strange characters" and what they should be.

Comment: I found this guide: http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8/mysql
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_database' and SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_client' both said latin1, so I changed it to UTF-8 according to the guide (also added your lines to my files).
The � is an example of a strange character replacing a single char (all å, ä and ö).

Comment: Finally everything works!
Turned out I had to use the "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>" tag in the html head, "header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');" on top of the <?php tag, the "mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);" right after the db was chosen and the accept-charset="utf-8" in my <form> tag to get it to work.
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Wow this just helped me solve a problem that took hours of debugging to find the culprit characters.
One thing I learned along the way that would add to this answer would be to also make sure that your database tables are also set for UTF-8 collation.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would use backticks (`) to surround the table name. Nothing to do with Character-encoding:

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$table` (FirstName, LastName, StartDate, TimeStroke, DueDate, Duration, Price, Retailer, Checksum)
VALUES ('{$_POST['firstname']}','{$_POST['lastname']}','{$_POST['startdate']}','{$_POST['timestroke']}','$duedate','{$_POST['duration']}','$price','{$_SESSION['name']}','$random')");
```

A couple of side notes here:

A: you should really user mysql_real_escape_string on any input coming in from an unknown source to avoid someone destroying your database with SQL Injection.

B: You should use ' around array associative indexes, reason being is that these all would throw notice undefined constant (or something to that matter) errors. Which will fill up your error log and make finding more critical errors a bit harder if you ever need to go back.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however the backticks did not solve the problem. It's the same result as not using ticks at all. The å, ä and ö gets all twisted and replaced by a string of strange characters.
Any other suggestions? Meanwhile I read up on character encodings. :)

Comment: The backticks was part of the problem for your query. But yes, you will need to change the charset to UTF8 would be my guess as it is probably some version of latin at the moment.

Comment: You can't use single quotes on hash references when interpolating inside double-quoted strings, UNLESS you've surrounded the array reference with `{}`. Right: `"$_POST[firstname]"`. Right: "{`$_POST['firstname']}"`. Wrong: `"$_POST['firstname']"` (parse error: unexepected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE).

Comment: Marc B, you are correct, did you see my code above? I did add them in there, but thanks for elaborating as I did leave out the full explanation.